# Creating chat rooms automatically associates them with another SE site

Tags: support, chat

When I try to create a chat room in math, it is automatically created in Tex.SE. Is this because that is where I have the highest rep? Is there any way for me to create a room in the SE I am in instead of it automatically going to Tex.SE?

Comment: When I click on [create new room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) I see fields Room Name, Description and *Related Site*. In "related site" I see Mathematics, but I can click on "more sites". Do you see the same, but with TeX instead? What happens if you try to choose Mathematics in "more sites"?

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes. Why is it prefilled for TeX when I starting the process from Math?

Comment: I don't know that. It might be highest rep.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think it would be a nice feature for it create where you are starting the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you go to create a chat room, the parent site of the room to be created is defaulted to the parent site of your chat user. This can be found (and changed) in your chat user profile:

[image: chat user profile and parent user]

(Note that it may take a bit of time for this change to filter through the system.)

Note, too, that in the dialogue box to create a chat room you are also able to choose a site other than the default option:

[image: create chat room dialogue box]

Just click on "(more sites...)" and start typing the name of the site you want the room to be associated with.

Comment: There is no option to pick the related site when you click “start a new room with this user” from a user profile. That's how I've ended up with rooms under my default site.